# Bootstrap 4 display buttons in 2x2 form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and I need to set 4 icon buttons like 2x2 form:

So:

> Button 1               button 2
>
> Button 3               button 4

But what I am having is:

> Button 1
>
> Button 2
>
> Button 3
>
> Button 4

My Html code is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/2013.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">

        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <a href="patient.php" style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Client</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">

        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <a href="#" style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Sale</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">

        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <a href="#" style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Store</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">

        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <a href="#" style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-database fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Report</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should i change in my code so it would take the 2x2 form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<style>    
.col-sm-12 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
}
</style>

<div class="row ">
<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <a href="#" style="width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Sale1 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <a href="#" style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Sale2 </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <a href="#" style="width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Sale3 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <a href="#" style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Sale4 </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to align them in the center ?

Comment: @droidnation: just updated the code. please have look and let me know

Comment: In regards to pull-* I believe that is replaced in version 4 with float-*